# Why the shorthand syntax to declare/init variables?

Tags: go

Is there a difference between these 2 styles of variable declaration/initialization?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var a = "I am a string"        // Declare + init (infer)
    fmt.Println(a)

    b := "I am a string"           // Declare + init (shorthand)
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

I fail to see the added value of the shorthand syntax, and inclined to use the "var" statement for consistency throughout my code.

Comment: i like the first one better :3 *just personal opinion*

Comment: Both do the same job. However gofmt or the go team defines that you use the shorthand syntax over the infer one. And as this is the convention I suggest to do so. You will just be "forced" to use `var` when defining globals.

Answer (score 6):

I always try to use the `:=` syntax. The benefit is huge when you need to Refactor code.

You are not binding the name of the variable to any particular type and any time you change the right hand side's type the variable would automatically infer the new type.

Answer (score 5):

I only use var when necessary, like:

1) global variables

2) if statement like:

```
var err error
if x == nil {
    err = errors.New("x is nil")
} else if y == nil {
    err = errors.New("y is nil")
}
```

...